# Local History via telemetry

Tags: visual-studio-code, local, telemetry

## I have a question for Local history

### *Is local history transfered via telemetry?*

```
If yes, can I receive my local history data via email or other ways.
I have turn on enable telemetry all since use VSCode.
```

#### Reason 1

```
I had a planned to develop a python module using Local history files 
which time spent and more information per project daily.
```

#### Reason 2

```
Even though I had backup to D drive,but now impossible.
Due to initialization my all local drives during Windows 11 installation.
It was my fault, didn't check the options.
```

## Please let me know my question.

#### PS.

```
Local/User history is VSCode function which tracking per file.
Can check in timeline tab in VSCode


The location of Local history is as below in case Windows system
%APPDATA%/Code/User/History
%APPDATA% = C:/Users/{USERNAME}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean with `User History`

Comment: A history files under %APPDATA%/Code/User/History in windows system  
There is entry timestamp in entries.json and files.
Maybe we can see timeline in VSCode using these files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.